# Closed-form expression for a recursive formula

Tags: linear-algebra, closed-form, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to calculate the closed-form expression of the recursive

$a_n = \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{3}$

Where $a_0 = 0, $ $a_1 = \frac {1}{3}$, and $a_2 = \frac {1}{9}$

I have tried to mimic the matrix method of calculating the fibonacci sequence (since this is so close to it), but I didn't understand how the eigenvalues and whatnot all were supposed to end up. I think many of the signs got messed up, but I based my method off of the article https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/the-linear-algebra-view-of-the-fibonacci-sequence-4e81f78935a3

I also know the next 5 or so values, so if those would make the calculations easier, I can do that. Thank you.

Comment: $\left(\frac{1}{3^n}\right)F(n-1)$, where $F(n)$ is the $0$-indexed $n$-th term in the Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: $a_n = k^n$ works, provided that... $$3k^2 - k - 1=0$$

Comment: Your expression is missing an assignment.

Comment: $3^n a_n$ is [A006130](https://oeis.org/A006130)$(n-1)$ for $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 1):

The general method to solve linear recurrence relation is by using the associated characteristic equation.

First rewrite it: $\quad a_n-\frac 13\,a_{n-1}-\frac 13\,a_{n-2}=0$

Then the characteristic equation is: $\quad r^2-\frac 13r-\frac 13=0\iff 3r^2-r-1=0$

It has roots $r=\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt{13}}6$

Therefore the solution is given by $$a_n=\alpha\,r_1^n+\beta\,r_2^n$$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are calculatated to fit the initial values of the sequence.

The reason behind this is given here for instance:
[Recursively given sequence question about changing the sequence with exponent function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037081/399263)

In our case $\begin{cases}a_0=\alpha+\beta=0\\a_1=\alpha r_1+\beta r_2=\frac 16(\alpha+\beta)+\frac{\sqrt{13}}6(\alpha-\beta)=\frac 13\end{cases}\iff \alpha=-\beta=\frac 1{\sqrt{13}}$

Finally $$a_n=\frac 1{\sqrt{13}}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}6\right)^n-\frac 1{\sqrt{13}}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{13}}6\right)^n$$

Notice also that $\ b_n=3^na_n$

verifies $3^na_n=3^{n-1}a_{n-1}+3^{n-1}a_{n-2}\iff b_n=b_{n-1}+3b_{n-2}$

And since $b_0=0$ and $b_1=1$ are integers, then $b_n$ is an integer by induction.