# Linear Recurrence Relation with addition

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

If given the equation $$a_n=\frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}}{3} + 6$$

where $a_{1}=\frac{1}{3^3}$, $a_2=\frac{3}{3^4}$ (which equals $a_1$).

How do I make this non-recurring the same way I would do it with a regular fibonacci sequence? My question is the extra 6 in the equation. From the examples I've seen of transforming a recurrence relation, there haven't been any with a lone digit. What do I do with the 6?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Calculate $a_{n+1}-a_n$ using the recurrence, then get a recurrence for $a_{n+1}.$

---

The alternative approach is to let $b_n=a_n-18$ and show that:

$$b_n=\frac{b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}}3$$

---

The first approach works more generally, but the second approach works often, too.

Comment: Okay I did the calculation and got $a_n$ but I don't see how that helps me calculate the linear recurrence. I did it for the same equation without 6 here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4146222/closed-form-expression-for-a-recursive-formula

Comment: What did you get for $a_n?$

Comment: $a_n$ is defined already, unless i'm missing something

Comment: Yeah, but what happened when you did what I recommend in the answer? You get another recursion for $a_n.$

Comment: Yea, does that mean I have the answer? I still need the closed form expression and I don't know how to get it from this.

Comment: You still aren’t answering my question. What did you get when you did what I recommended?

Comment: I got $a_n$. Like when i subtracted those two things i got the term $a_n$. I'm trying to do what you say but you're confusing me.

Comment: Then you did it wrong. @gamelizard

Comment: $$a_{n+1}-a_n =\left(\frac{a_n+a_{n-1}}{3}+6\right)-\left(\frac{a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}}3+6\right)$$

Comment: okay so you get $a_n/3 - a_{n-2}/3$

Comment: Adding $a_n$ to both sides, and you get a formula for $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n$ and $a_{n-2},$ it’s no constants.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124982/discussion-between-gamelizard-and-thomas-andrews).

Answer (score 0):

If you define $b_n=a_n+18, $ you get
$$ b_n=\frac{b_{n-1} + b_{n-2}}{3}      $$